# OpenTok missing audio in audio/video conference session

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, voip, avaudiorecorder, opentok

I'm developing iOS app with ability to establish audio/video calls powered by OpenTok.
I tested it on devices iPhones with iOS 7.x and iOS 8.x with integrated OpenTok iOS SDK 2.3.0.

At some moment during the app usage we are trying to start a new OpenTok Audio/Video session and getting an error from the OpenTok SDK (in DEBUG output only, no ability to handle that via the SDK).
While a video conference is in progress audio is no longer available.

The error is below.
What is interesting we still could record and playback audio within the app after that error (we have such a functionality beside the OpenTok sessions).
But all the subsequent OpenTok sessions goes without audio and we have to restart the app to have it work again.

```
09:55:41.768 ERROR: [0x11f55000] 1230: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (-66637)
ERROR[OpenTok]:Audio device error: AUGraphStart error: ˇ˛˚≥
09:55:41.811 ERROR: [AURemoteIO::IOThread] >aurioc> 1497: AURemoteIO@0x1684ec20: IOThread exiting with error 0x10004006
09:55:42.464 ERROR: [0x11f55000] 1230: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (-66637)
ERROR[OpenTok]:Audio device error: AUGraphStart error: ˇ˛˚≥
09:55:43.917 ERROR: [AURemoteIO::IOThread] >aurioc> 1497: AURemoteIO@0x1684ec20: IOThread exiting with error 0x10004006
09:55:44.596 ERROR: [0x11f55000] 1230: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (-66637)
ERROR[OpenTok]:Audio device error: AUGraphStart error: ˇ˛˚≥
09:55:44.612 ERROR: [AURemoteIO::IOThread] >aurioc> 1497: AURemoteIO@0x1684ec20: IOThread exiting with error 0x10004006
09:55:45.268 ERROR: [0x11f55000] 1230: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (-66637)
ERROR[OpenTok]:Audio device error: AUGraphStart error: ˇ˛˚≥
09:55:46.609 ERROR: [AURemoteIO::IOThread] >aurioc> 1497: AURemoteIO@0x1684ec20: IOThread exiting with error 0x10004006
09:55:47.261 ERROR: [0x11f55000] 1230: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (-66637)
ERROR[OpenTok]:Audio device error: AUGraphStart error: ˇ˛˚≥
09:55:48.195 ERROR: [AURemoteIO::IOThread] >aurioc> 1497: AURemoteIO@0x1684ec20: IOThread exiting with error 0x10004006
09:55:48.838 ERROR: [0x11f55000] 1230: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (-66637)
ERROR[OpenTok]:Audio device error: AUGraphStart error: ˇ˛˚≥
```

OpenTok sessions work fine at the test app, but in the real app where we have other code which manages AVAudioSession modes and categories we experiencing the issue above.

UIViewController which initialize OpenTok session
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83972129/OpenTokDevViewController.cs

Please advise how to diagnose and fix the issue.

Comment: Have you found a way to correct these errors ?

Comment: unfortunately - no. Users are still reports missing audio (sometimes) during audio/video call

Comment: After some investigations, it appeared that (we're using cordova, with opentok & some sound plugin) that the combination of the sound plugin and Opentok was causing some issues. Removing the sound fixed our issues. Are you using some sound libraries aside to play audio files ?

Comment: no, only AVAudioPlayer. What is the library caused you issues?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it was the sound library used by cordova's library, can't really tell if it's AVAudioPlayer or not, it would need to go through the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Try to play with the

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:??? error:nil]
```

It can be that you set the category in your app which does not work with Opentok.

Comment: solution worked for me, after commenting out the following code, opentok did not product the audio error...  // on iphone, play through speaker, not earpiece
    [session    setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker
                      error:nil];

Answer (score 0):

if playing audio before
then open audio unit(AudioOutputUnitStart) will be post this error

i have make this: (call setCategory first then to open audio unit, and it working fine iOS 12.4.1)

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *error;
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
         withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker error:&error];

OSStatus status = AudioOutputUnitStart(audioUnit);
```